# Best way to run some codes on certain controllers - Laravel 5

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel-5

I am working on a project that has a control panel with a topbar that contains details about the user like username, email, image url etc. This topbar runs on almost all control panel views. Right now in every controlpanel controller i do something like this

```
/***** PostController *********/
class PostController extends Controller
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $user = Auth::user(); // Note: here $user is not a global variable

        $this->user['user_name']  = $user->name;
        $this->user['user_email'] = $user->email;
        $this->user['user_role']  = $user->getRolesName()->first();
        $this->user['user_image'] = $user->image;
    }
```

Then in the index controller i would pass the current user with role, and the posts details like this.

```
 public function index()
    {
        $user = $this->user;
        $posts = json_decode( Post::with('author')->get()->toJson() );
        return view('globaladmin.posts.viewposts',compact('posts'), $user);
    }
```

I think there might be a much better way of doing this (maybe a design pattern like repository), Like always any help  would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something called a view share. If you look at the documentation (http://laravel.com/docs/master/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) you'll be able to create a service provider that you can place your code in.

A quick (potentially dirty) fix is to use app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php like so:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $user = Auth::user(); // Note: here $user is not a global variable
    $global_user = [];

    if ($user !== null) {
        $global_user['user_name']  = $user->name;
        $global_user['user_email'] = $user->email;
        $global_user['user_role']  = $user->getRolesName()->first();
        $global_user['user_image'] = $user->image;
    }

    view()->share('global_user', $global_user);
}
```

Edit: to use this in blade, something like this will work:

```
@if($global_user)
    {!! $global_user->user_name !!}
@endif
```

Comment: I like this approach and i also did some reading to add it to the boot method of the AppServiceprovider But the problem is that these controllers and service providers are instantiated way before the Auth method. So placing the code in the controller.php doesn't do anything. i guess the best place to put this code would be inside the Auth Controller itself

Comment: Auth::user() should return data within Controller.php if you're logged in, do you get any errors when you try to place the code in there, or is it simply a null value?

Comment: yes its just a null, it doesn't process the if statement. I think the problem is that this code needs to wait for the controller.php to process the auth controller first, because if we just place a constructor in the controller.php it will run this code before even instantiation the auth controller. Anyways the Share method helped a lot and i ended up creating a ServiceProvider and then sharing it with all the views :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you got simple data to share, I advice you to use **[Service Injection](http://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#service-injection)** simply add this code snippet to you master blade template:

```html
@inject('user', 'App\User')
```

then use `$user` in every template that extending the master one:

```
<div>
    Username: {{ $user->user_name }}.
    ...etc
</div>
```

**btw:** you don't have to share this since inside `auth()` global function you've access to you current logged in user like so:

```php
auth()->user()->name // or ->email maybe!
```